# Android, location continously changes even with an accuracy check of 20 for every location

Tags: java, android

I have been developing an app that keeps track of distance run/walked by a user.

I used the `FusedLocationProviderClient` with a foreground service. I set the following parameters for the `LocationRequest` object,

```
mLocationRequest.setInterval(3000);
mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(500);
mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(6.4008) //7 yards
```

And, for getting location updates,

```
mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
       @Override
       public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
           super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
           Location location = locationResult.getLastLocation();

           if (mLocation == null) {      

               if (location.hasAccuracy() && isLocationAccurate(location)) {
                   mLocation = location;
                   isGpsAccurate = true;
               }

            } else {

                if (location.hasAccuracy() && isLocationAccurate(location))
                        calculateDistance(location);
            }
      }
};

mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, 
                          mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
```

Here's the code for `isLocationAccurate(location)`,

```
boolean isLocationAccurate(Location location) {

    float accuracy = location.getAccuracy();

    return accuracy > 0 && accuracy < MIN_ACCURACY;
}
```

And Here's the code for `calculateDistance(location)`,

```
private calculateDistance(location){
     distance += mLocation.distanceTo(location);
     mLocation = location;
}
```

That's the code, works well when moving, but when stationary and indoors(sometimes outdoors), the value keeps changing.

Am I doing something wrong here?

**Note: I verified with Strava and Runkeeper. Distance remains constant over there. So, my device(ONE PLUS 3T) works fine.**

Answer (score 0):

*There is a getSpeed() function

simple format is

`if(location.getSpeed() > 50){
calculateDistance(location);
}`

so if the device is in movement means tracking will started otherwise no need to track, just show marker in the last updated position

Comment: Hi, this really helped a lot,  though the speed value of 50 seem a little too much for a walk/run tracker. I did some walk tests, found the speed to be around 1 most of the time. So, I kept the condition as 0.5 meters/sec. This worked, but in 2 cases the speed were about 2 or even 4 meters/sec, for a location accuracy of 10 meters(with device stationary). Speed did not drop to zero

Comment: Also, is there any alternative to getSpeedAccuracyMetersPerSecond() for api level 21. I could use this to filter out inaccurate speeds